# Raw sockets: How should I define TCP flags(keeping byte order in mind) and when to use hton function?

Tags: sockets, endianness

I read a tutorial(http://mixter.void.ru/rawip.html) about how to create your own IP and TCP headers and send them using raw sockets. I am having two doubts which are related to the OS byte order. I am using Linux on Intel x86.

First,how to define TCP flags?

```
#define TCP_URG 1
#define TCP_ACK 2
#define TCP_PSH 4
#define TCP_RST 8
#define TCP_SYN 16
#define TCP_FIN 32
```

Or

```
#define TCP_URG 32
#define TCP_ACK 16
#define TCP_PSH 8
#define TCP_RST 4
#define TCP_SYN 2
#define TCP_FIN 1
```

Another doubt from the same tutorial is that while creating the ip and tcp header, some fields are converted into network byte order and then stored in the header whle others are stored as they are. e.g.

```
iph->ip_ttl = 255;
```

and

```
 iph->ip_id = htonl (54321);
```

Why is this?

**Edited:** When I am trying to run this ip spoofing program on my machine, sendto is returning with the error "Permission denied" (though I am running it as superuser). Why is this happening and how to correct it?

Answer (score 0):

The `ip_ttl` field is only one byte, so byte order is not relevant. On the other hand, `ip_id` is 16 bits, so here the byte order is relevant.

Since the value assigned to `ip_ttl` is going to be truncated to the first byte, you should not use `htons`/`htonl` on it because the macros implicitly promote your integer to a larger type and the byte that you're interested in might be truncated away.

Your first set of flags is right.

Comment: But in the tutorial the author has not used htonl for ip_len though it is also 16 bits. Also, why is htonl is used instead of htons( which is used for 16 bit values). I am really confused so kindly explain...

Comment: @Naman Mishra The site is blocked from my job computer, I'll check when I'll be back home.

Comment: @Naman Mishra The only relevant place he doesn't use `htons` or `htonl` is for `ip->ip_len`, and I'm fairly sure this is a mistake.